# Snow Leopard desktop - I want two files from two different applications open at the same time. Won't let me

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, desktop

I want two files open at once on the desktop.  However when I click on one, it opens and the other minimizes.

What can I do?

Comment: Are these different applications, different windows in one application? Which application?

Answer (score 2):

Have you per chance turned on "[Single App Mode](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20081229062620506&query=disable)"? This hidden preference causes Mac OS X to hide all applications but the current active one.

You can tell by running the following command in Terminal.app:

```
defaults read com.apple.dock single-app
```

If it prints a `0`then it is not turned on. If it prints a `1` then yes, it is turned on.

You can disable this trick by running:

```
defaults write com.apple.dock single-app 0
```