# Is this possible to auto-hide an application when switching to another one?

Tags: macos, mac

I would like the application to hide when I leave it and switch to another one. I don't want the application to be hidden in the dock, but I would like to have the windows of that application to be hidden on my screen.

Exactly what the "Hide" command does (in the right click menu on the application icon in the dock) but done automatically, not been forced to do it each time by hand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To hide the previous application, hold down the option key when switching to another application.

Comment: Nerdling, any idea if it's possible to disable this behaviour? I'd like to use option+click for something else.

Answer (score 0):

[Isolator](http://willmore.eu/software/isolator/) can be configured to do this. It also has some other fancy options like an overlay to "blur" out the windows of background apps and desktop which I particularly like.

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use a little feature called "Single App Mode". Another Super User question; [Snow Leopard desktop - I want two files from two different applications open at the same time. Won’t let me.](https://superuser.com/questions/153457/snow-leopard-desktop-i-want-two-files-from-two-different-applications-open-at-t) had a user who may have turned this on. The feature will automatically hide applications when you switch to them.

The easiest method however is as Nerdling mentioned; hold the option key down when changing the application (it doesn't work with <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd>)